# How do I loop the login and password verification process?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

I'm new to this business. There is such a situation that you need to test the process of entering the correct username and password. I use selenium webdriver.
But the process of creating without a cycle is very long and tedious. For example, here.

```
let element0 = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));   
  element0.click();   
  element0.sendKeys("admin");
  await driver.sleep(1500);
  element0.clear();
```

I need to loop so that the first element is taken from the array of logins and passwords - inserted into the login and password fields, checked and deleted, etc.

I tried to use a for loop, but outputs all the elements of the array.

```
async function fillLoginPassBox() {
  let element0 = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
  let element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="password"]'));
  let logins = ['test0', 'test1', 'admin'];
  let passwords = ['test0', 'test1', 'admin'];      

    for(let key in logins) {
      element0.sendKeys(logins[key]);
      element0.click();
      element0.clear();
      console.log(logins[key]);
    }
   // element0.click();
   // element0.sendKeys("admin");  
      await driver.sleep(1500);                                         
      element1.click();
      element1.sendKeys("admin");
      await driver.sleep(1500);
      return element1, element0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Do you see any error?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium, I do not know how to make a loop correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want all within this single method (and it would be a bad practice to attempt to do so). Each method should do only 1 thing, e.g. login. It keeps reading comprehension high and maintenance low.

While it seems "better"/faster to do all these login attempts in a single script and browser, it's actually a bad practice as well. Your best bet would be to write a single login script and then pass it the sets of login credentials and run it in parallel.

A sample login script would be

1. Create a browser instance
2. Navigate to the login page
3. Log in with the current set of credentials
4. Verify that you've logged in successfully
5. Log out
6. Verify that you've logged out successfully
7. Quit the browser instance

You will also want to investigate a data driven test given the framework that you are using. It could be attributes that you pass to this test, etc. depending on the syntax. Now you have a single login test and a set of credentials that are passed in and you can run all your tests in parallel which in the end will make your tests run much faster than using a single instance and you'll have much fewer issues, e.g. imagine running 10 logins and the third one fails if you were using a single browser. You'd have to rerun all the tests. In the parallel case that I've described, you would get a failure message for credentials #3 but the rest would pass. Then you could investigate the 3rd set, etc. rather than having to rerun everything.